# Spring singleton bean creates new instance/bean on a each method call when proxied

Tags: java, spring, proxy, prototype, scopes

Bellow is the code. When you run it and go in the browser to localhost:8080/hello you will see sequences "1,2", "2,3"...,because Spring CGLIB proxy (which is actually inserted into prototype field) creates new bean on every method call.

I think the prototype bean should be created only once per http call so the output should be "1,1", "2,2"..

I can solve this with ObjectFactory, but then I am loosing proxy along with all AOP spring capabilities.

How is this supposed to behave? Do I have st wrong? Is this really limitation of Spring? Can it be somehow solved with Java-based config?

This is the whole code, you need only 2 files:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    @Autowired  //one solution is ObjectFactory<PrototypeExample>
    private PrototypeExample prototype;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return (prototype.getCounter() + ", " + prototype.getCounter());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
@Scope(value = SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = TARGET_CLASS)
class PrototypeExample {

    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public PrototypeExample() {
        counter.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter.get();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.neco</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core_IV</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You have prototype scope, and it behaves exactly as it should: by creating new bean on each request to it. Try either removing proxy, or using different scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your bean `PrototypeExample` has a `SCOPE_PROTOTYPE` scope attribute.

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) :

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the
>   creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific
>   bean is made. That is, the bean is injected into another bean or you
>   request it through a getBean() method call on the container. As a
>   rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton
>   scope for stateless beans.

If you need a singleton, just remove the `@Scope` annotation or set it to `singleton` (which is the default one). All scopes available are listed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes).